# Get album id from photo id

Tags: facebook, api, upload, photo

When I upload a photo an album is automatically created. There's a way in which I could get the album ID from having the photo ID. Because I have this code:

```
    try {
            $response = $facebook->api(
                    '/me/photos/',
                    'post',
                    array(
                            'message' => 'This is my image caption',
                            'source' => $source
                            )
                    );

            $id = $response['id'];
            if ($id) {
                    //obtenemos la url del album                                                                                                                                
                    $response = $facebook->api('/'.$id);

                    unset($_SESSION['uploaded_file']);
                    header('Location: http://www.facebook.com/'.$id);
                    exit();
            }
    } catch ...
```

And I want to redirect the user to the albums (because I need the user to aprove the photos) instead of the photo. There's a way of doing this without actually asking for all user albums and checking where was the photo uploaded?

Answer (score 0):

If I didn't oversee anything, there is no way to get the album id of the automatically created album.

As a workaround you can upfront create a new album for your application by using the [`albums` connection of the `User` object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#albums). In the response you get the album id which you can use to [upload photos specifically to this album](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/) and later redirect to it using the [`link` attribute in the Album object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/).

Answer (score 0):

You can get that info using FQL – first query the `photos` table for the `aid` of the album, and then query them `album` table with that:

```
SELECT object_id FROM album WHERE aid IN
  (SELECT aid FROM photo WHERE object_id = "{your photo’s Graph API id}")
```

– the `object_id` will be the Graph API id of the album.